# Is it possible to improve the efficiency of solving a non-relativistic problem by using a relativistic theory?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, field-theory

There are many beautiful theories, especially quantum field theory, start with covariant formulation compatible with relativity. But apparently most phenomena in atomic physics, material sciences, chemistry, biology, etc., are well-governed under non-relativistic physical rules. Is it possible, or is there any case already existed, that a relativistic or relativity-like formulation can simplify a non-relativistic problem?

Comment: Using Noether's theorem to find conservation laws that are valid in a non-relativistic context?

Comment: Would you consider a problem in Electromagnetism to be "non-relativistic"?

Comment: @Philip EM field is definitely relativistic, in principle. But my question is not when we encounter relatively, but whether we need relativity when we are already in non-relativistic conditions. For example, it is cool to write down the EM field as a tensor, and use some differential geometry to compress everything into one equation. But if we are dealing with a photonic material, we want to know the transmission, radiation, scattering, etc., is it really worthwhile to start with that heavy stuff, or is it even meaningful to learn this?

Comment: @ZhouYijia For example, the four-vector formalism makes calculating the electric and magnetic fields for certain configurations (single moving charge, for example) much easier than doing it using the "standard" methods. If this interests you, I could write a short answer, but I'm not sure if it's the sort of thing you want to know about since the underlying theory is indeed relativistic, even if the laws (Coulomb, Biot-Savart, etc) are not manifestly relativistic...

Comment: @Philip Thanks for your reply. This is interesting to me, and was actually where I began to have this question. I saw my tutors use four vector, fiber bundle, Green's function, path integral, blabla to solve ... a free electron, or a single HO?!! But photonics, as an example again, at least requires Drude model. In many-body systems, we care about interactions, dissipation, relaxation, etc. As Jerry mentioned, it sounds interesting if four vector formalism can tell us some 'hidden' symmetris and conservation laws, but I have little knowledge how it works.

Answer (score 3):

A good example would be the problem of cosmological evolution of homogeneous and isotropic universe filled with gravitating matter.

When considered within the framework of general relativity theory the solution to the problem is the [Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric), a relatively simple spacetime determined by  two ordinary differential equations that has been found within years after publication of general relativity theory and is described in almost every GR textbook.

That same problem, when considered within the framework of Newtonian gravitational theory (referred to as “Newtonian cosmology”) has not been solved satisfactorily until *decades after* the relativistic case, though originally it was formulated by Newton himself who gave an erroneous solution (that such universe would be static).

The difficulties of the Newtonian case are traceable to the fact that infinite number of bodies attracting one another  via Newton's law produce diverging results (if done in the straightforward way), whereas relativistic Einstein's field equation describe how *local* spacetime geometry is determined by *local* matter content. Once a suitable set of local variables is introduced in the Newtonian problem, it becomes solvable as easily as its relativistic counterpart.

For historical account and discussion of conceptual problems in Newtonian cosmology see the paper by Norton:

- Norton, J. D. (1999). *The cosmological woes of Newtonian gravitation theory*. The expanding worlds of General Relativity: Einstein studies, 7, 271-323, [pdf on author's homepage](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Ejdnorton/papers/cosmological-woes-HGR4.pdf).

While for pedagogical exposition of the actual rigorous solution for that problem see Tipler:

- Tipler, F. J. (1996). *Rigorous Newtonian cosmology*. American Journal of Physics, 64(10), 1311-1315, [doi:10.1119/1.18398](https://doi.org/10.1119/1.18398).